# Constructing symmetric matrix on R

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal, symmetric

I want to construct a 1000x1000 symmetric matrix where all diagonal elements are 1 and others are 0.5.  I don't know how to do this for such a large matrix.  Can someone help me out here?

Thank you!

Comment: `diag(1000)/2 + 0.5`

Comment: @statsfox consider using `toeplitz(c(1,rep(0.5,999)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(0.5, ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
diag(m) <- 1
```

Comment: Simple! Thank you very much.

Comment: @statsfox - if this answer solves your post consider accepting it - click on check mark to the left

Comment: @statsfox you should use `toeplitz(c(1,rep(0.5,999)))`

Comment: @AshOfFire you should consider `toeplitz(c(1,rep(0.5,999)))`

Comment: @Onyambu this actually answers another problem I encountered later today! Thank you very much